# Is it possible to lock a customized Excel 3D Map do that the user can't adjust the configuration?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I want to be able to set up a customized map using the 3D Maps feature in Excel 2016. Since the same file map will be shared between various users on OneDrive, I don't want the users to be able to adjust the configuration of the map such as the variables shown, filters used, etc. Is there a way that the map can be locked up with in the workbook without having to export it?

Comment: Isn't that what tours are for? Record a tour and share that with the end user, instead of the whole workbook?

Comment: The data feeding the workbook is updated frequently. I want to avoid having to create a new tour everytime there's an update.